# How can I get rid of a nonexistent disk that appears in /dev as a "ghost" of my SD card (Debian GNU/Linux)?

Tags: linux, debian, sd-card

I have a "ghost" disk registered in `/dev`.
The disk doesn't actually exist - it looks exactly like my SD card (size, partition label and fs) that used to be plugged into the card reader. The card is long since gone from the slot (with many system reboots), but the disk still appears among devices (also shown as plugged into the SD slot in KInfoCenter). As a result, whenever I plug in a real SD card, no new device is recognized by the system, and I can't access the actual card anymore.
There is nothing wrong with the card reader - it works fine if I boot into Windows.

The disk is listed as `/dev/sdc`

P.S. This happened after a major update of the system several days ago.

EDIT:
output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 500.1 GB, 500107862016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 60801 cylinders, total 976773168 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0xbf5fbbd1

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1            2048    33556479    16777216   27  Hidden NTFS WinRE
/dev/sda2   *    33556480    33761279      102400    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda3        33761280   268136447   117187584   83  Linux
/dev/sda4       268140976   976768064   354313544+   5  Extended
/dev/sda5       268140978   289121804    10490413+  82  Linux swap / Solaris
/dev/sda6       627338313   976768064   174714876    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sda7       289121868   627338249   169108191    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT

Partition table entries are not in disk order

Disk /dev/sdb: 2000.4 GB, 2000396746752 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 243201 cylinders, total 3907024896 sectors
Units = sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disk identifier: 0x00066778

  Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdb1   *          63  3907024064  1953512001    7  HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
```

output of `cat /proc/partitions`:

```
major minor  #blocks  name

  8        0  488386584 sda
  8        1   16777216 sda1
  8        2     102400 sda2
  8        3  117187584 sda3
  8        4          1 sda4
  8        5   10490413 sda5
  8        6  174714876 sda6
  8        7  169108191 sda7
  8       16 1953512448 sdb
  8       17 1953512001 sdb1
 11        0    1048575 sr0
```

sda and sdb are my two hard drives

Comment: Can you please post the output of *fdisk -l* and of *cat /proc/partions/? Ty

Comment: @MariusMatutiae edited my post with the outputs.

Comment: Actually, I was wrong to panic about sdc appearing in /dev - it seems that all my card reader slots are there. It was the KDE info tool that freaked me out by listing my card as connected and having a partition

Comment: Right: there is nothing anomalous in the output of the two commands, no trace of a ghost partition.